# Properly using the Navigation Property in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I am working on a form to add new inventory into an inventory tracking database I designed. I have done a mapping to EF and I am using LINQ to EF to query data.

The equipment table has a navigation property `EquipmentInventories`. Consider the following snippet of code:

```
public partial class Content_AddInventoryItems : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Equipment equipment;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MSSInvDBEntities myEntities = new MSSInvDBEntities())
        {
            var manuPop = (from equipment in myEntities.Equipments
                           select equipment.equipmentManu).Distinct();
            ManuList.DataSource = manuPop;
            ManuList.DataBind();
        }
        using (MSSInvDBEntities myEntities = new MSSInvDBEntities())
        {
            var modelPop = from equipment in myEntities.Equipments
                           select equipment.equipmentModel;
            ModelList.DataSource = modelPop;
            ModelList.DataBind();
        }

    }

    private void DisplayEquipmentData()
    {
        ManuList.SelectedValue = equipment.equipmentManu;
        ModelList.SelectedValue = equipment.equipmentModel;
        tboSerial.Text = equipment.EquipmentInventories.serialNumber;

    }
}
```

However I keep getting errors when I try to reference the `serialNumber` property of the `EquipmentInventories` object using the `EquipmentInventories` navigation property of the `equipment` object.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: Is this a 1:N relation, do you have lazy loading, what error are you getting? you need to supply more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you instantiate your public field `equipment`. (`equipment` in `from equipment in...` is another variable, the range variable for the LINQ query.) Looking at your code I'd expect a `NullReferenceException` because `equipment` is `null`.

You should have something like:

```
using (MSSInvDBEntities myEntities = new MSSInvDBEntities())
{
    equipment = (from e in myEntities.Equipments
                 select e)
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But this would cause an exception as well because you don't load the `equipment.EquipmentInventories` property and lazy loading won't work in your `DisplayEquipmentData` method because you already have disposed the context (automatically at the end of the `using` block). Lazy loading requires a context which isn't disposed yet.

In your case I would use eager loading though:

```
using (MSSInvDBEntities myEntities = new MSSInvDBEntities())
{
    equipment = (from e in myEntities.Equipments.Include("EquipmentInventories")
                 select e)
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then the navigation property is loaded at once with this query and you can safely dispose the context.

Answer (score 0):

What Slauma said, or...

```
private void DisplayEquipmentData() 
{ 
    ManuList.SelectedValue = equipment.equipmentManu; 
    ModelList.SelectedValue = equipment.equipmentModel; 
    if (!equipment.EquipmentInventoriesReference.IsLoaded)
        equipment.EquipmentInventoriesReference.Load();
    tboSerial.Text = equipment.EquipmentInventories.serialNumber; 

}
```